# React Native FlatList is giving error that It doesnot be nested inside scrollView

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, native-base, react-native-scrollview

I am using native base, and the error is for flatlist that it contains inbuild scroll view no need to nest it into scrollView
[image: react native flatlist]
Image 1 code:

```
<Container>
    <Content>
        <View>
            ***
        </View>
        <FlatList 
            {...props}
        />
    </Content>
</Container>
```

Image 2 code:

```
<View>
    <View>
        <View>
            ***
        </View>
        <FlatList 
            {...props}
        />
    </View>
</View>
```

I want both parts to scroll without error, can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to slightly modify your structure

```
<View>
  <ScrollView>
    <View>
        ***
    </View>
    <FlatList 
        {...props}
    />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Content` in nativebase is basically a scrollview.

You can make use of `FlatList`'s `Header and Footer Component functionality. and mark content above FlatList as Header and content bellow it a footer.

```
const ContentAbove=()=>(
  <View>**</View>
)

//Then inside the component
-----
<Container>
    <FlatList
            ListHeaderComponent={<ContentAbove/>}
            ListFooterComponent={<ContentBelow/>}
            {...props}
        />
</Container>
```